# Problema usando Malloc y Realloc

Tags: c

Debo hacer un programa en el que le pida al usuario su nombre, después su apellido y al final mostrarle su nombre completo.

Debo guardar el nombre en un espacio de memoria usando `malloc` o `calloc` y después debo redimensionar el espacio con `realloc` para solicitar su apellido y almacenarlo en el espacio de memoria sin que este quede encimado y al final debo imprimir el nombre completo.

Mi problema viene siendo lo que está como comentario en el código: al momento de solicitarle su apellido al usuario el programa termina inmediatamente, pero al descartarlo al ponerlo como comentario y poniendo el valor por mi mismo este funciona.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main (){
    char *p_nombre, *p_apellido, *p_nombrecompleto;
    char *nombre, *apellido;
    p_nombre = malloc (10 * sizeof(char));

    printf("Escribe tu nombre: ");
    gets(p_nombre);
    fflush(stdin);
    
    printf("p_nombre = %s \n", p_nombre);

    p_nombrecompleto = realloc(p_nombre, 30 * sizeof(char));
    
    printf("Escribe tu apellido: ");
    gets(p_apellido);
    fflush(stdin);
    
    //p_apellido = "Aqui deberia estar tu apellido :(";

    printf("Tu apellido es: %s\n", p_apellido);
    strcat(p_nombrecompleto, " ");
    strcat(p_nombrecompleto, p_apellido);

    printf("Tu nombre completo es: %s \n", p_nombrecompleto);
    free(p_nombrecompleto);
    return 0;
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1):

El problema es que nuncas pediste memoria para `p_apellido`

Aqui está la corrección:

```
printf("Escribe tu apellido: ");
p_apellido = malloc (10 * sizeof(char));
gets(p_apellido);
fflush(stdin);
```

Comment: No me habia dado cuenta, muchas gracias bro :3

Answer (score 0):

Tu error es que estás almacenando en un puntero sin inicializar algo, y eso provoca core dumped o null en tu caso. Usa malloc primero para alojar a la variable que mantiene el apellido y después almacena.

Comment: ¿Cual puntero? ¿Dónde está el código correcto?

Comment: Eres grande hermano, tenias razon, muchas gracias :3

Comment: no le voy a hacer la práctica, le ayudo, no le hago la tarea, así @hotcske314 piensa un poco sobre el error.

Comment: @Tmpuser302948gjskskUserAccou6. Para eso están los comentarios. Aqui van las respuestas, que deben ser demostradas.

Comment: Yo tengo entendido que esto es un foro de dudas, no de hacer los deberes ajenos.

Comment: Creo que el punto no era que me hicieran la tarea ni mucho menos, aunque entiendo tu punto Tmpuser302948gjskskUserAccou6 dandome cuenta del error que tuve si es algo que si hubiera puesto mas atencion o pensando un poco mas tal vez lo hubiera resuelto, pero @CandidMoe Moe tiene razon al responder una pregunta debes poder demostrar que tu respuesta es correcta o al menor te deben guiar a al resultado correcto, aun asi muchas gracias a los dos :)